# Retrieving values from the J SON sub array

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to retreive the values present in the JSON Array.However,my code is  failing to get it executed.Below posted is how the file looks like.

```
   {

     "meta" : 
          {

          "view" : 
             {


             "description" : "This data set shows the location of Baltimore  
                              City's  Services.",
             "columns" :
                          [ {

                             "cachedContents" : 
                                              {

                                               "top" :
                                                      [
                                                      {
                                         "item" : "American Rescue Workers"
                                                       }]

                                                      }]      

                                                       }
                                                       }
```

My Apologies if my JSON file has got some syntax issues.I am trying to access the item element present in cachedContents.Below posted is the code.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $.get("https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/hyq3- 
      8sxr/rows.json",function(data)
      {
            $.each(data.meta.view,function(i,obj)
                {
                      if(i=="name")
                         $("#result").append("<p align='center'>"+obj+" 
                          </p>");
                      if(i=="description")
                       $("#result").append("<p align='center'>"+obj+"</p>");
                       if(i=="columns")

                      var length = data.meta.view.columns.length;
                                     for(i2=0;i2<length;i2++)
                                     {


                  $.each(obj[i2].columns.cachedContents,function(i,obj[i2]){
                  $("#result").append("<p align='center'>"+"Hello"+"</p>")   
                                    });



                                     }  });  }); });
```

The error i am getting is

```
      SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters
      $.each(obj[i2].columns.cachedContents,function(i,obj[i2]){
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: `function(i,obj[i2]){}`.  You can't use `obj[i2]` as a parameter name in a function signature.

Comment: Can you tidy up your question. It's way too hard to read. I'd edit it myself but I'm watching the Great British Potter!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to name a parameter `obj[i2]`, which isn't legal.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already pointed out you're using illegal parameter names. What you are doing in this case is creating an anonymous function for the callback and declaring the parameters. Javascript will take care of passing the obj[i2] value into the function.You may also consider not using i2, i3, i4, etc. as it becomes difficult to read with more complexity.

Also, your code could use a bit of work to make it easier to work with and more efficient.

Most importantly you are using the JQuery selector inside of a loop which requires the program to traverse the DOM each time. Instead you should cache the object like so: $result = $("#result");

You were checking the state of "i" in a redundant manner by having multiple if statements. Instead one statement for both name and description makes it faster and then use else if so that if it returns true in the first case it won't have to do the second check.

Lastly, creating a named function and passing it in as a callback is more readable and helps with modularity and re-usability as opposed to creating a string of anonymous functions.

The code provided should hopefully work, although I don't have the rest of your project to test it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function someFunction(){

    $.get("https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/hyq3-8sxr/rows.json", parseData(data));

    function parseData(data){
      var $result = $("#result");  

      $.each(data.meta.view, appendData(index, value))

      function appendData(index, value){
        var leng;

        if(index === "name" || index === "description"){
          $result.append("<p align='center'>"+value+"</p>");
        }else if(index === "columns"){
          leng = data.meta.view.columns.length;
        }

        for(var j = 0; j > leng; j++){
          value[j].columns.cachedContents.forEach(
              function(val){
                $result.append("<p align='center'>"+"Hello"+"</p>");
              }
            );
        }
      }
    }

  }


});
```